# Mopub: Custom Native Adapter for Smaato

Tags: android, mobile, ads

Has anyone written a Mopub custom native adapter for integrating the Smaato SDK?

Google search didn't turn up anything useful. Just wanted to check before writing something myself.

Comment: you ever found a way to integrate?